# Refresh Bearer Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, refresh-token

I am working in a Power Automate solution which does read data from O365 via Graph API. As, the operation is running more than an hour, the bearer token gets expired.

I have implemented a logic to perform an REST call to regenerate the Bearer Token whenever it fails from the refresh token and ran the failed operation again in a DoUntil loop. But, as I have many calls performed via Graph API , I need to write the logic elsewhere in the Flow.

Pls do let me know whether there are any simple way to regenerate the Bearer Token from the Refresh Token.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

We would recommend start looking at the [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) published by Microsoft. Microsoft recommends using [MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) and MSAL library provides token caching and get fresh token when it's getting close to expiration. For more details on token caching please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#acquiring-tokens-silently-from-the-cache).

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in a variable and  use a parallel branch and get a new token in every 15 or 20 minutes. User the token variable in all API calls